# SQL: convert backup file from copy format to insert format

Tags: sql, postgresql, phppgadmin

I have a PostgreSQL backup made with PHPPgadmin using Export > Copy (instead Copy > SQL which is actually what I need).

File contains entries like this:

```
COPY tablename(id, field) FROM stdin;
...
```

How to convert this file to SQL format?

```
INSERT INTO tablename...
```

I want to use Pgadmin to to import this file using execute SQL command.

Comment: You mean phpPgAdmin, no ? (Pgadmin is a desktop client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't convert that to SQL format (at least not straightforwardly).

If you can't re export, then the simpler option is to bypass *phpPgadmin*,
login in your server and run something like

```
cat [yourdump.sql]  | psql [your connections args]
```

If you don't have shell access to your server, you might try you upload the file (via SFTP or FTP)  and load it thorugh phpPgAdmin with `"COPY <table> FROM <path_to_file_on_server>"`. But if there are many tables, you must (I believe) split the file and do it one at a time.

http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/?page=faq

Answer (score 9):

I don't know a way or a tool which can convert "COPY" into "INSERT" statements.

But with the "pg_dump" command line tool you can create a DB dump file with "INSERT" instead of "COPY" statements. Simple use the "--column-inserts" argument (may be "--inserts" is also ok for you).

**EDIT:**

What you can do is:

1. Create a new postgres database on your local machine
2. Import your DB dump file into the new created database

   ```
   psql -U <dbuser> <database> < dump.sql
   ```
3. And create a postgres dump with "--column-inserts" from that database

   ```
   pg_dump --column-inserts -U <dbuser> <database> > dumpWithInserts.sql
   ```

Answer (score 5):

I've wrote a tool to convert copy-from dump to inserts dump :

https://github.com/freddez/pg-dump2insert

You can use it to load a dump in another database or search for specific deleted values for example.

Comment: Nice tool! Works even 5 years later

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Can you convert a file for me, please?

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me a lot of time. Works really well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try **COPY FROM PROGRAM** syntax, available since PostgreSQL 9.3

For example:
`COPY tbl_customers (id, address_id, insurance_id, fullname, secret_code ...) FROM PROGRAM 'echo "1    2    \N    Ivan Ivanov     42 ..."'`

Answer (score 0):

To add on [Steffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1465758/steffen) answer, it is nice to also add `--rows-per-insert` (added to pg_dump for v12) if you want to have one big insert for all your values :

```
pg_dump --column-inserts --rows-per-insert=2147483647 \
        -U <dbuser> <database> > dumpWithOneInsert.sql
```

(inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/60621069/19888529)